# Prism.Forms with native layouts

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, prism

I have a question surrounding the PCL. From all that I read up it is my understanding that you can only use Prism.Forms with PCL, when the views are in the portable library (ie. the xaml views and not in the native libraries). Am I mistaken? Is there a way to use prism with native layouts?

I want to use Prism in my xamarin app but I want to create native layouts for Android & IOS. But I cannot figure out how to make Prism navigate from page to page and how to tie the ViewModel to the layout as there is no AutoWireup option in the native.

So it seems that Prism is a xaml only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism for Xamarin.Forms (Prism.Forms.dll) only supports Xamarin.Forms.  It does not support Native Xamarin iOS or Android.

Answer (score 0):

Hi asked this same question on Brain Lagunas blog and he aswered me back:
Prism.Forms only worlks with Xamarin.Forms, it doesn’t work for Native Xamarin for iOS or Android.

Thanks Brain